# Ricci tensor of Metric black holes with nils and solv geometries of Horizon

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, differential-geometry

The metric of black holes with nils and solv geometries of the horizon is generically represented by

$$\mathrm{d}s^2=-r^{2z}\mathrm{d}t^2+\frac{\mathrm{d}r^2}{r^2}+\sum_{I=1}^3 r^{2q_I}(w^I)^2$$

How does one calculate Ricci tensor for this metric in a general way namely without using the explicit form of 3-geometry Thurston? Is it possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The expression in the picture is very difficult to read. We use [MathJaX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020) here to render formulae. Also, have a look at [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) (even if this is not actual homework), because currently it seems you are "just" asking us to calcuate the Ricci tensor.

Comment: Also, what are the $w^{I}$?  are they a tetrad basis on the three-space?  is $r$ a coordinate on them, or do we expect $r$ to be a function of the $w^{I}$?  If so, what of the $dr^{2}$ term above?  Are the $q_{I}$ constants?  This is a strange-looking metric to me.

Comment: What are "nils and solv geometries"?

Comment: It should be said that I am not 100% certain that I got the exponent of $r$ in the sum term correct. I think that $I$ is a subscript of $q$, but it might be just another exponent.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: Certain types of homogeneous spaces: [Nil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilmanifold) and [Solv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvmanifold)